# Do BPF filters work inside Docker containers?

Tags: python, linux, docker, bpf

I have some Python code that opens a socket and attaches a BPF filter to it using `socket.setsockopt(..., SO_ATTACH_FILTER)`.  Unfortunately the code that generates the filter is a bit tangled up with other stuff, but there's a runnable outline below demonstrating what I'm trying to do.  The filter checks that the EthernetType field is `ETH_P_IP`, the IP protocol is `IPPROTO_UDP` and the destination port is 68 - this should be limiting packets to only DHCP responses.

Running the script below with `sudo python3 test.py` on the host results in a timeout every time unless I manually do a DHCP lease renewal before the timeout happens (or very occasionally if something renews a DHCP lease on the network).  But if I do the same thing inside a Docker container with host-mode networking, it almost never results in a timeout, there's always a packet received and it's almost never a DHCP response.

The docker container is running with `--privileged --net=host` and as the root user.

Is there something I have to do to get a packet filter to work inside a container?  Or is it just not possible?

```
import ctypes
import struct
import socket

ETH_P_ALL = 0x0003
SO_ATTACH_FILTER = 26

filters = bytes([0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00
0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0xff, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0xb1,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x15, 0x00,
0x00, 0x01, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xdc, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])

b = ctypes.create_string_buffer(filters)
mem_addr_of_filters = ctypes.addressof(b)
pf = struct.pack("HL", 11, mem_addr_of_filters)

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
    sock.bind(("eth0_bridge", ETH_P_ALL))
    sock.settimeout(2)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, pf)
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1500)
    except:
        print('Timeout')
        exit(-1)
    print('No timeout')

main()
```

Comment: There's a missing comma at the end of the first line of your `filters` byte array. Just to be sure, is this just a copy-paste error and do you have that comma in your code?

Comment: Does `tcpdump ip proto \\udp and dst port 68` work in your container? It should use the same filter.

Comment: @Qeole - Yes, the tcpdump works as expected.  However, this turns out not to be specific to the docker container so I'm going to start another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that BPF filters are only applied as data is *received*, not as the process takes the data off the socket buffer.  So there is a window between the socket being bound (`sock.bind(...)`) and the filter being applied (`sock.setsockopt(...)`) where packets that don't match the filter can be received and buffered.  The subsequent call to `sock.recv(1500)` will receive such a packet even though it doesn't match the filter.

The only way to avoid this problem appears to be to use this sequence:

- Set the socket to non-blocking mode
- Apply the filter
- Receive packets until there are no packets to receive
- Set the socket to blocking mode
- Set the socket timeout
- Receive the packet you are interested in.

This drains any non-matching packets that were received between binding and the filter being applied.  Of course, it may also miss packets you are interested in.  That's not an issue for my scenario, but may be for yours.